# .exe crated using Par::Packer with script containing Net::SSH2 is not working

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl, net-ssh, pp-perl-par-packager, perlnetssh

Am using Net::SSH2 module in my Perl script and trying to make an executable (.exe for windows) using Par::Packer. The script need to ssh to a linux box from a windows box using public keys and don't want to input password.

Am facing the below error while running the .exe

> Can't load
>   'C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\par-73656172756d7567616d\cache-a6d57d5a234829aae84d08c4a78a09ad307ea8d3\a9057da2.xs.dll'
>   for module Net::SSH2: load_file:The specified module could not be
>   found at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193. at
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 123.

Tried to workaround with the below methods but none of them worked

1. Tried to pack from a portable version of Strawberry Perl
2. Tried to link a9057da2.xs.dll while packing using Par::Packer

Is there any workaround or fix for packing the perl scrip to .exe with Net:SSH2.
Or are there alternatives to Net::SSH2 for ssh from windows to Linux using public keys (not passing passwords)?

Answer (score 2):

If you get something like:

```
Can't load D:\TEMP\par-76696b616d7768\cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93\7c34139c.xs.dll' for module XML::LibXML: load_file:The specified module could not be found at <embedded>/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
at <embedded>/PAR/Heavy.pm line 140.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at D:\TEMP\par-76696b616d7768\cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93\inc\lib/XML/LibXML.pm line 156.
Compilation failed in require at script/test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/test.pl line 3.
```

then add the following test code 
(*check your path to Listdlls.exe and fix the below as needed*)

```
#This is the code causing the issue
use XML::LibXML;
my $x = XML::LibXML->new();

ListPerlDLLs();

sub ListPerlDLLs
{
  my @ret =  `C:\\"Program Files"\\Sysinternals\\Listdlls.exe  $$`; # $$ : current PID

  foreach my $line (@ret)
  {
    $line =~ s/\s$//;
    next if $line !~ /^0x\w+\s+\w+\s+(.+)/;
    my $dll = $1;
    next if $dll =~ /^c:\\windows\\/i;
    print "$dll\n";
  }
}
```

The Listdlls.exe is from Microsoft - see [**SysInternals**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls) \

First, double-click Listdlls.exe to accept the disclaimer 
(will ask for approval on first launch).

When you run the **Perl** script, you will get something like this:

```
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/bin/perl.exe
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/bin/perl532.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/bin/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/bin/libwinpthread-1.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/bin/libstdc++-6.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/lib/auto/Encode/Encode.xs.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/lib/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.xs.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/lib/auto/Storable/Storable.xs.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/lib/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.xs.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/lib/auto/IO/IO.xs.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/vendor/lib/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.xs.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/libxml2-2__.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/libiconv-2__.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/liblzma-5__.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/zlib1__.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/perl/lib/auto/List/Util/Util.xs.dll
```

if you build your EXE and run it, you will get something like:

```
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/test.exe
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/perl532.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/libwinpthread-1.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/libstdc++-6.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/5461bd7b.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/1ed3ae5b.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/89b9c18b.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/18f23f26.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/0e796a00.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/5d0ea4ea.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/d3d27bc6.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/d8bcc032.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/64916f0f.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/76c6a0cc.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/6b1ff21f.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/4eceebd6.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/ebaed210.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/831f407e.xs.dll
D:/TEMP/par-76696b616d7768/cache-48ca417d0c47dd7f7245a1218d8d6614470afa93/7c34139c.xs.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/libxml2-2__.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/liblzma-5__.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/zlib1__.dll
D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/libiconv-2__.dll
```

The last four are the missing DLLs - 
add them with `--link` parameters:

```
call pp test.pl -o test.exe --link D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/libxml2-2__.dll --link D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/liblzma-5__.dll --link D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/zlib1__.dll --link D:/strawberry-perl/c/bin/libiconv-2__.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not packing the `libssh2` and `openssl` DLLs inside the executable.

`Par::Packer` does not detect DLL dependencies automatically, you need to tell it explicitly which ones your program needs (a simple way to discover which DLLs your program needs is to use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), an utility which allows one to monitor process activity).

Another option is to use my module [Win32::Packer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Packer) to pack the application which does find DLL dependencies automatically.